# What is the probability that 8 unique and randomly selected two digit numbers will be in ascending order?

Tags: probability, statistics, computer-science, order-statistics

A computer will randomly generate 8 unique (no repeated numbers), two-digit numbers (10-99) and assign them a position from 1-8. I'm trying to find out the probability that the numbers will be in ascending order relative to their assigned positions. So the table generated would look something like this:

Position: 1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
Value:     a        b        c        d         e        f         g        h

where a, b, c, ... h are random numbers from 10-99

Again, given that a-h must all be unique, two-digit numbers, what is the probability that a sequence in which a<b<c<d<e<f<g<h will occur?

Please let me know if any of this isn't clear and I'll do my best to rephrase. Thank you in advance for you help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there are $8! = 40320$ possible order permutations (such as $e<g<a<c<f<b<d<h$, and so on), and each of them has equal probability to happen, so by symmetry, the probability the case $a<b<c<d<e<f<g<h$ that you want indeed happens is $1/40320$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! How would one calculate the probability that 3 numbers will be in ascending order with the added condition that the first position value counts as something like "the largest so far" and there need to be 2 numbers in the sequence after the first number that are larger than the first number and in ascending order. For example, 20, 21, 22, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 Will work because 20, 21, 22 match the criteria but something like 20, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 would not count because they don't asced relative to the first number.